# Which dialect of LISP is 'Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming' written in?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

What version/dialect/implementation of LISP is this meant to run on?

(I do understand that the book is written in Common LISP (as specified in the introduction) and that it predates the 1994 CL standard).

---

Split question into two to make it clearer.

Comment: It's called "Paradigms of AI Programming", not "Principles..."

Comment: Can you show the function you're reading?

Comment: From the first line of the link you provided: `;;;; -*- Mode: Lisp; Syntax: Common-Lisp -*-`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at [auxfns.lisp](http://norvig.com/paip/auxfns.lisp) found on Peter Norvig's [web page for the book](http://norvig.com/paip.html), there's this bit

```
(eval-when (eval compile load)
  ;; Make it ok to place a function definition on a built-in LISP symbol.
  #+(or Allegro EXCL)
  (dolist (pkg '(excl common-lisp common-lisp-user))
    (setf (excl:package-definition-lock (find-package pkg)) nil))

  ;; Don't warn if a function is defined in multiple files --
  ;; this happens often since we refine several programs.
  #+Lispworks
  (setq *PACKAGES-FOR-WARN-ON-REDEFINITION* nil)

  #+LCL 
   (compiler-options :warnings nil)
  )
```

which suggests its supposed to work in Franz Allegro, Lucid Lisp, or Lispworks

Answer (score 7):

Those aren't functions. Those are variable bindings. Not everything that appears as the first thing in a form is the name of a function; the enclosing form may introduce special meaning to internal forms. That's the case with e.g. `let`:

```
(let ((action 42)
      (result 51))
  (+ action result))
```

Neither `action` nor `result` names a function in that example.

Comment: Those *are* bindings. They're introduced by the lambda list.

Answer (score 3):

The dialect of Lisp is called 'Common Lisp'. The book is written in relatively portable Common Lisp.